# How to give script a name?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a script that I run to keep my computer from going to sleep. It's a simple script that presses the Num Lock key. How can I give my script a name so I can see it in Task Manager? I would like to end the process every now and then and not sure which application it is.

**Here is the code (idle.vbs):**

```
Dim objResult

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    

Do While True
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (60000)
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is being executed in an interpreter, and in Task Manager you will see the name of the executable : `wscript.exe`

You cannot change the process name, although you can identify the name of the running script using another script and the property of handles.

But the easiest way would be to make a copy of the executable `wscript.exe`, rename it with something suggestive for you, and use that executable in cmd to run the script. For example `idleEx.exe` and run it :

```
...\idleEx.exe idle.vbs
```

Or, the other method: create a shortcut for the vbs and change Properties / General / Opens with, browse and choose `idleEx.exe`.

After that, your process name will apear as  `idleEx.exe`